# Field 'owner' suddenly undefined in AWS Amplify GraphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, null, graphql

Today I tried to add a 'name' field to the 'User' type of my AWS GraphQL schema. After running "amplify push" and "code gen", I received an error from AWS saying that 'owner' was null. After comparing my git history side by side, I found that codegen deleted the autogenerated owner field in my queries while simultaneously adding two new fields, 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt'. Unsure how/why this was happening, I reverted to an earlier git commit where everything was working fine and pushed to amplify. All my files were reverted back to a commit where everything was working perfectly. However, I am still receiving errors that 'owner' is null. GraphQL schema and screenshots of terminal are below. Happy to provide other files (queries, mutations, etc.) if helpful.

```js
type Image {
  bucket: String!
  region: String!
  key: String!
}

type Circle
@model
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  username: String!
  password: String
  bio: String
  avatar: Image
  favors: [CircleFavor] @connection(name: "CirclesFavors")
  users: [CircleUser] @connection(name: "CirclesUsers")
  pendingUsers: [User] @connection
  tags: [String]
  admin: User @connection
  isPrivate: Boolean!

  poster: ID!
}


type Favor
@model
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  description: String
  location: String
  deadline: AWSDateTime
  circles: [CircleFavor] @connection(name: "FavorsCircles")
  price: Float!
}

type CircleFavor
@model(queries: { get: "getCircleFavor" })
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  circle: Circle! @connection(name: "CirclesFavors")
  favor: Favor! @connection(name: "FavorsCircles")
  poster: User! @connection(name: "UsersFavors")
}

type User
@model(
  queries: { get: "getUser" }
  mutations: { create: "registerUser", update: "updateUser" }
  subscriptions: null
)
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  bio: String

  email: AWSEmail
  isRegistered: Boolean
  orders: [Order] @connection(name: "UsersOrders")
  circles: [CircleUser] @connection(name: "UsersCircles")
  favors: [CircleFavor] @connection(name: "UsersFavors")
}

type CircleUser
@model(queries: { get: "getCircleUser" })
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  circle: Circle! @connection(name: "CirclesUsers")
  user: User! @connection(name: "UsersCircles")
}

type Order
@model(
  queries: null
  mutations: { create: "createOrder" }
  subscriptions: null
)
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  favor: Favor @connection
  claimer: User @connection(name: "UsersOrders")
  additional_costs: Float
  isCompletedByClaimer: Boolean!
  isApprovedByPoster: ApprovalStatus!
}

enum ApprovalStatus {
  PENDING
  APPROVED
  DISPUTED
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: You dropped those fields from the database.  The owner data is gone, which is why it's coming back NULL now that you re-added it to the schema.